# What is appropriate response a 404 or a 401 for this REST endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an endpoint to get a User for example. If the user is not found it would be a 404.
If I ask for some data for that user and that doesn't exist it is a 204.

If I ask for some data for a user, but the user doesn't exist. In this case is it a 404 or a 401?

It seems to me that it is a 404. But consider the following scenario...

There is a REST client who is making the request to the REST server. The REST server (which uses spring security) tries to load the user first but fails to load because the user doesn't exist in the system. Because the spring security sees UserNameNotFound exception it throws a 401. This seems correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should never intentionally send 404. 404 would be used when we are calling an API that doesn't exist.

So if you throw 404, the client would assume they are calling the wrong API or the API is not available.

If there is no data, 204 is apt, 204 tells that you are calling correct API and server acknowledges it but there is no response to provide from server side.

Hence either there is no user or user has no data, it should be 204 as status.

2XX - success
3XX - request moved
4XX - bad request 
5XX - server error

Comment: I don't think `204` is suitable for this situation. A `200` with an empty array/object would be better.

Comment: I kind of agree @CássioMazzochiMolin , but if you want to rely on status rather than to verify response data to see if it's empty or not, 204 is best bet.

Answer (score 10):

Use `404` when the client requests a resource that do not exist:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server
> did not find a current representation for the target resource or is
> not willing to disclose that one exists. A `404` status code does
> not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
> permanent; the `410` (Gone) status code is preferred over `404` if the
> origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
> the condition is likely to be permanent. [...]

If you are using [HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235), use `401` when the client requests a resource and the credentials are not valid (authentication problem):

> [**3.1.  401 Unauthorized**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)
>
> The `401` (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has
> not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials
> for the target resource.  The server generating a 401 response MUST
> send a `WWW-Authenticate` header field containing at
> least one challenge applicable to the target resource. [...]

For more details, check the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol. Also have a look at the following [decision chart](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) from Racksburg:

The status codes are grouped into three rough categories:

[image: HTTP status codes categories]

Start here:

[image: HTTP status codes]

Choosing `2xx` and `3xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 2xx and 3xx status codes]

Choosing `4xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 4xx status codes]

Choosing `5xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 5xx status codes]